Can ultraproduct arguments be paraphrased using internal set theory?
Since Nelson's internal set theory is basically an axiomatic way of working with ultralimits, I expect that proofs using ultralimits can be paraphrased as a proof in IST.
Is this the case?
For example:
Proposition.
A finite system $E$ of polynomial equations and inequations with integer coefficients has a solution in some field $K$ of characteristic 0 if, for every natural number $n$, there is a field $F_n$ of characteristic $> n$ in which $E$ has a solution.
Proof by model theory.
Let $K$ be a non-principal ultraproduct of the fields $F_n$ given in the hypothesis.
Then $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$ (by construction) and also has a solution for the system (by Łoś's theorem).　◼
Proof by internal set theory (maybe).
For a field $K$, let $\chi (K)$ be the set of all natural numbers $n$ such that the map $\{ m \in \mathbb{N} : m < n \} \to K$ sending $m$ to $1 + \cdots + 1$ ($m$ times) in $K$ is injective.
Then $\chi (K) = \mathbb{N}$ if and only if $K$ is of characteristic $0$, and for $n > 0$, $\chi (K) = \{ m \in \mathbb{N} : m < n \}$ if and only if $K$ is of characteristic $n$.
(For the purposes of this proof, it is more convenient to think about $\chi (K)$ than the usual characteristic of $K$.)
Let ${}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K)$ be the standardisation of $\chi (K)$, i.e. the standard subset of $\mathbb{N}$ such that, for a standard natural number $n$, $n \in {}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K)$ if and only if $n \in \chi (K)$.
By transfer, if $K$ is standard, then either $\chi (K)$ is standard finite (i.e. the characteristic of $K$ is standard positive) or $\chi (K) = \mathbb{N}$ (i.e. the characteristic of $K$ is $0$).
Thus, if $K$ is standard, $\chi (K) = {}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K)$; but if $K$ is nonstandard, it is possible that $\chi (K)$ is (nonstandard) finite while ${}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K) = \mathbb{N}$.
Assuming $E$ and $n$ are standard, by transfer, there exists a field $K$ such that $n \in \chi (K)$ and $E$ has a solution in $K$ if and only if there exists a standard field $K$ such that $n \in {}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K)$ and $E$ has a standard solution in $K$.
By transfer, the proposition is equivalent to:

A standard finite system $E$ of polynomial equations and inequations with standard integer coefficients has a standard solution in some standard field $K$ with ${}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K) = \mathbb{N}$ if, for every standard natural number $n$, $E$ has a standard solution in some standard field $F_n$ with ${}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K)$ finite and containing $n$.

Assume the modified hypothesis: $E$ is standard, and for every standard natural number $n$, $F_n$ is a standard field with ${}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K)$ finite and containing $n$.
Each $F_n$ is a field with characteristic $> n$, so by idealisation or transfer, there is a (nonstandard) field $F$ such that the characteristic of $F$ is illimited (i.e. greater than any standard natural number) and $E$ has a (nonstandard) solution in $F$.
Clearly, ${}^\mathrm{S} \chi (F) = \mathbb{N}$.
But now I am stuck: how do I get from $F$ a standard field $K$ such that ${}^\mathrm{S} \chi (K) = \mathbb{N}$ and $E$ has a standard solution in $K$?
(Do I need to write out the compactness argument implicitly behind the model theory proof...?)

I. In general, one can paraphrase these simple ultraproduct arguments in a much more direct way using Internal Set Theory. Here's how one would do it in your specific case.
By Transfer, assume that everything in sight is standard, including

The equation $E$,
the assignment $(F_\bullet,+_\bullet,\cdot_\bullet,0,1)$,
The assignment $i_\bullet$ so that $\forall n. \forall x \in F_n. x = 0 \vee x \cdot_n i_n(x) = 1$,
The assignment $e_\bullet$ which assigns a solution $e_n \in F_n^m$ to the system $E$ in $F_n$.

Take the product ring $\displaystyle F = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n$, and using the fact that it is standard define the standardized relation $R = ~^S\{ (x,y) \in F^2 \:|\: x(\omega) = y(\omega) \}$. I claim that $R$ is an equivalence relation. Since $R$ is standard, it suffices to prove that it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive for standard $x,y,z \in F^2$. But there the Standardization scheme reduces it to the claim that equality itself is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
You can verify that $F/R$ is a standard field (just invert sequences pointwise using the fact that $i_\bullet$ is standard) and that $E$ still has a solution (using the assumption that $e_\bullet$ is standard).
Since $F/R$ is a standard field, it has a standard characteristic. Can it have a standard $k>0$ as its characteristic? Well, $k \neq 0$ in $F_\omega$ since by assumption $F_\omega$ has prime characteristic $> \omega > k$. It follows that the class $[k] \in F/R$ is not equal to $[0]$ either. We have shown that the characteristic of $F/R$ is standard, but not positive standard, so it must be zero.
Of course, one can do this in full generality, where it is really just a proof of Łoś's theorem. But a similar approach allows one to paraphrase arguments using metric ultraproducts (see 1.3.43 of my PhD thesis).
II. I don't think there's a short way to finish your specific attempt, since the nonstandard field $F$ you obtain this way can be very "degenerate". For example, consider what happens if you start with a sequence of fields $F_n$ defined as isomorphic to the usual field structure on the $n$th prime number $p_n$, but expressed on the underlying set $\{n,n+1,\dots,n+p_n-1\}$. Then the resulting $F$ has no standard elements whatsoever, so if you apply Standardization to it, you'll just get the empty set. But you'll probably have to apply Standardization to something at some point in the argument, since as far as I can tell you haven't done so yet, and IST minus Choice minus Standardization is not that strong a theory.
There are some cases where you can avoid the product/quotient construction in IST. This usually happens when you start off with access to a standard object on which the desired structure will be constructed. The IST proof of the De Bruijn - Erdős theorem is a classic example of this situation, where you start off with a standard graph $G$, and you want to construct a standard coloring $V(G) \rightarrow \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Yes, I was struggling with where to apply standardisation since the fields are all just free-floating rather than being subfields of some standard field or otherwise related to some standard rings. That must be how explicitly constructing $F / R$ as in your argument helps.

I see your thesis develops a MLTT analogue of IST... perhaps you already have some comments for this MO question.
